# multithreading or multiprocessing with a for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

So I have a code that is currently working. Data processing.
So I get a bunch of data delimited by new line.
My code is running on 1 by 1 process. I want to speed things up because processing leads for the company 1 by 1 takes a lot of time. Below is my code:

```
def at_answer(message):
    lines = message.text
    names_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in lines.splitlines()) if y]
    for x in names_list:
        lead = re.split("[: _=/+\-;]", x)
        currmonth = datetime.now().strftime('%m')
        curryear = datetime.now().strftime('%y')
```

I tried adding multithreading before the for x. but if I do so it will try to run multiple instances of one `x` in my list.
If I remove the `for x in names_list` and add it to the `def thread`, I don't know if my code is messed-up.

If someone can help me how to add multithreading or multiprocessing with the `for x in names_list:`.

Comment: Are you trying to process multiple names from the list in parallel?  You will want to spawn multiple threads within your `for` loop, possibly using thread pools if you have many names to process.  then you have to wait for the threads to terminate.

Comment: yes., i have many names. like 10.000. want tio process 5 at a time. but i have to split the customer data before processing in. so i have FOR and i want to add threading. if you can share an example it would be appreciated

Comment: You are aware that some types of processes will not benefit from multithreading.  If it is compute intensive, you will need to multiprocess.   However, if it is, for example, web access, multithreading works well, as each thread continues when its network request is satisfied, which aren't guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: Adding to what RufusVS said: "C Python" (the Python dialect that most people use) is incapable of using threads for parallel computing. Google for "Python" and "the GIL" to learn more. The workaround is to do what Rufus said; Use the `multiprocessing` module instead.

Comment: how to do it doesnt matter as long as it process 5 entries at the time in parallel. so if multiprocess would be better then i will use it. any example will be appreciated